# BASH, back tics or perens, and I can'y even debug the most basic of these…

Tags: bash, variables

```
#SETUP
dir_to_clean="/Users/$(whoami)/Downloads"

#Go to the directory we are going to work on
cd $dir_to_clean;
pwd
```

The above will output /Users/current logged in username/Downloads

However, I would like to use Parens "(" or ")" in my variables, and I can get it to work sometimes, but not at others;  For example, I a setting in double quotes, not sure the different between single and none, the value of dir_to_clean and the above code will work, the shell will `cd` where it needs to go, but I would rather cd $(some_variable_path).

If anyone can give me the run down on the down low, I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: I just tried this: dir_to_clean="/Users/me/Downloads"
#Go to the directory we are going to work on
cd $(dir_to_clean);
echo "I AM HERE: $(pwd)" and get ./clean_downloads.sh: line 24: dir_to_clean: command not found

Comment: `$(X)` means "run the command `X` and substitute its output". It has nothing to do with variables. `${X}` means "substitute the value of the variable `X`. Those are two completely different actions, so it is not surprising that they have different syntax. In both cases, you would normally want to put double quotes around the substitution.

Comment: rici: Why not write that as an answer?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you would like to know here. Is the question "why can't I use parentheses to expand parameters"? If so, @rici has answered your question. Either way, your wording is not clear enough and you should edit the question (and the title).

Comment: In addition to the other comments and answer, you can use `$(..)` and `backticks` interchangeably. `backticks` just being an older syntax. When you set a `variable=$(..)` you do not need to quote the `$(..)` (if it us used inside another string that would need quoting, then quote the whole thing). If as part of your command, quoting is required **inside** `$(.."$a".."${b}/${c}")` you may quote the command just as if it were not inside `$(..)`. When you need to debug, `set -x` immediately below `#!/bin/bash` to show all variable values during execution.

Answer (score 1):

`$(X)` means "run the command `X` and substitute its output". It has nothing to do with variables.

`${X}` means "substitute the value of the variable `X`".

Those are two completely different actions, so it is not surprising that they have different syntax. In both cases, you would normally want to put double quotes around the substitution:

```
#SETUP
dir_to_clean="/Users/$(whoami)/Downloads"

#Go to the directory we are going to work on
cd "${dir_to_clean}"
```